# Converting a Latex PDF into EPUB format

Tags: pdf, latex

Is there a way to take a technical article in PDF format (which typically contains latex formulas) and convert it into an epub format?  I wouldn't have access to the original latex files themselves, just the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/).

> calibre is a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books.

Source [Ebook Format Conversion](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#ebook-format-conversion)

> **What formats does calibre support conversion to/from?**
>
> calibre supports the conversion of many input formats to many output
>   formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to
>   every output format.
>
> Input Formats: CBZ, CBR, CBC, CHM, DJVU, DOCX, EPUB, FB2, HTML, HTMLZ,
>   LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ
>
> Output Formats: AZW3, EPUB, FB2, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, HTMLZ, PDB, PML,
>   RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ
>
> Note
>
> PRC is a generic format, calibre supports PRC files with TextRead and
>   MOBIBook headers. PDB is also a generic format. calibre supports
>   eReader, Plucker, PML and zTxt PDB files. DJVU support is only for
>   converting DJVU files that contain embedded text. These are typically
>   generated by OCR software. MOBI books can be of two types Mobi6 and
>   KF8. calibre fully supports both. MOBI files often have .azw or .azw3
>   file extensions. DOCX files from Microsoft Word 2007 and newer are
>   supported.

Comment: Converting PDF to anything else is always ugly and unpleasant.  Calibre does a better job than almost anything else, but it will scramble mathematical expressions (at best) or ignore them.  I have converted several PDFs to EPUB using Calibre.  Expect to spend lots of time fiddling with it.  And forget the math.

Comment: @unkilbeeg ah. I normally use it to go the other way ... :/